# Circuit to construct a $n$-qubit state which is a superposition of states with only a single qubit being $\lvert1\rangle$

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, gate-synthesis

So the question came up in a book I am working through. Given a circuit with $n$ qubits, construct a state with only $n$ possible measurement results, each of which has only $1$ of $n$ qubits as $1$, such as $|0001\rangle$, $|0010\rangle$, $|0100\rangle$, $|1000\rangle$, obviously normalized.

The only way I can think to do this is to take the all $|0\rangle$ input state, apply $\operatorname{H}$ to each qubit and then used multiple-controlled $\operatorname{CNOT}$ gates to affect the change on each qubit, but I feel like this won't lead to the desired end state.

To be clear, I am enquiring how to create a $W_n$ state can be arbitrarily prepared, given $n$ qubits.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "n possible measurement results" here. If you have $n$ qubits then there are $2^n$ possible measurement results. The rest of the question is fine and interesting though. I edited the title to better reflect what I think you are asking. Feel free to revert the edit if I misunderstood you

Comment: also, just for reference, states such as the one you refer to are often referred to as [W states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_state), and a similar question was also asked on physics.SE, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311743/58382. Finally, as pointed out in that question, you should really specify the set of gates that you want to use

Comment: @glS It appears the actual term for the state I was looking for is the W state, which has only n measurements.

Comment: again, I don't know what you mean by "has only n measurements". A state of $n$ qubits can have $2^n$ possible measurement results, it doesn't matter which particular state it is

Comment: @glS I am unsure how the example given there scales efficiently as the number of qubits increases, nor how they actually arrive at the state :/

Comment: depending on what you mean by "there" , you might edit your post accordingly to point out why the other question(s) do not answer yours. This will automatically put the question in the reopen queue

Comment: @glS Yes, a state has 2^n possible measurements, but only if it has been prepared in a fully parallel state. The W state has only n measurements, where n is the number of qubits.

Comment: no it doesn't, and again, you need to define what you mean by "has only $n$ measurements"

Comment: @glS The W state, as described in the links provided here, in the linear combination of n states, each with equal probability of measurement, each with only a single qubit shifted to 1, while the rest are 0. How does this state not only have n possible measurements?

Comment: @glS Also, what do you mean no it doesn't? If each qubit is not set up as an equal probabilistic distribution between 0 and 1, then how can the full range of 2^n states be achieved by measurement?

Comment: as I said, you need to define what you mean by "has only $n$ measurements", as it is not standard terminology and is not clear what it means. If what you mean is "*there are only $n$ measurement outcomes corresponding to a positive probability*", then sure, this is true

Comment: @gIS: for what it's worth, I find `luminalQubit`'s terminology fairly clear. A $W$ state *does* only have $n$ possible measurement results, because none of the other $2^n - n$ bit strings are 'possible measurement results' of the $W$ state.

Comment: @luminalQubit Hi. Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! You say: "I am unsure how the example given there scales efficiently as the number of qubits increases, nor how they actually arrive at the state". I suspect that you're confused about some particular steps/claims/assumptions in the answers to the [duplicate question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4350/general-construction-of-w-n-state). If so, could you please *elaborate*  which specific parts of those answers you do not understand, and edit it into the original question? Then we will be able to reopen your question.