# How to measure superposition coefficients to determine state?

Tags: quantum-state, mathematics, superposition

There was a [problem](https://codeforces.com/contest/1116/problem/B1) at the Winter 2019 Q# codeforces contest (that is now over), which I cannot find a mathematical solution for.

The problem goes like this:
You are given 3 qubits that can be in one of the following states:

$$|ψ_0⟩=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\left(|100⟩+ω|010⟩+ω^2|001⟩\right)$$

or

$$|ψ_1⟩=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\left(|100⟩+ω^2|010⟩+ω|001⟩\right)$$

where $ω=e^{2iπ/3}$.

Build a function that determines in which of the 2 states are the 3 qubits.

My question is, how could you solve this problem in linear algebra (bra-kets notation) and the normal quantum logic gates? I figured out you have to somehow measure the coefficients, but I don't know quite how. If you could include a "code algorithm proof of concept" that would be great, but I am mainly interested in understanding the algebra part. After understanding it, implementing would be just a problem of translating the operations/gates.

If I got something wrong, please correct me. I am new-ish to the whole quantum computing scene.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! It is preferable that you use [MathJax](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49) to typeset your posts. Review [How to write a good question?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to apply a unitary transformation which will map these states to a different pair of orthogonal states which are easy to distinguish by measuring in computational basis.

---

Let's construct a unitary $U$ which prepares $|\psi_0\rangle$ starting from $|000\rangle$ state.

The first step is to prepare a $W_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(|100\rangle + |010\rangle + |001\rangle\right)$ state, as described in [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4350/general-construction-of-w-n-state).

After that you just have to apply the $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ phases to the states $|010\rangle$ and $|001\rangle$ - this can be done using rotation gates. Depending on the primitives you have, you can do it using [R1](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.r1) gate, like the authors' solution, using Rz gate if you're ok with some accumulating some global phase, or using zero-controlled Rz.

---

Now, what happens if you take the states $|\psi_0\rangle$ and $|\psi_1\rangle$ and apply the adjoint of the transformation $U$ to them? You know that the state $|\psi_0\rangle$ will be transformed to $|000\rangle$, and the state $|\psi_1\rangle$ will be transformed to some other state. It doesn't really matter what state it is, it's enough to know that it is orthogonal to $|000\rangle$. So to distinguish these states you can measure all qubits after applying $U^\dagger$ - if you get all zeroes, you know it was $|\psi_0\rangle$, otherwise it was $|\psi_1\rangle$.

---

You can find a more detailed explanation and the code for this problem in the [contest editorial](https://assets.codeforces.com/rounds/1116/contest-editorial.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! it was exactly what I was looking for. Do you think you can give me an example of a rotation gate that will apply the w phase just to |010>, but not to the others? After this, I'll gladly mark the question as answered, since it's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Tudor I've edited the answer with the examples of the gates.

Comment: @Tudor Please let me know if you need more details :-)