# How to generate a quantum circuit from the quantum state $|1000\rangle+|0100\rangle+|0010\rangle+|0001\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-state, circuit-construction, textbook-and-exercises

I am trying to understand the steps of how make a state preparation circuit from a quantum state.
For making my question more clearer, for example, for the state is  $\frac{|00\rangle+|11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$, the state preparation circuit is :[image]

I want to draw the state preparation circuit for the quantum state  $\frac{1}{2}( |1000\rangle + |0100\rangle + |0010\rangle + |0001\rangle)$.

I was following [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MzfYflRHEY&list=PLGn8CrGvAJ0padfIA6fHhTsmOrDQU2oax&index=3).
I am not able to completely understand the steps used to draw circuits. It would be great if someone can help me with this question.

Comment: [Nielsen and Chuang - Chapter 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information)

Comment: Thank you @Rammus for providing me the link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entanglement distribution of W-State over different locations](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17742/entanglement-distribution-of-w-state-over-different-locations)

Comment: Hi @MartinVesely ,my question is different. I am looking for techniques to draw the circuit. If somehow, I can get the quantum circuit, it would be a great help.

Comment: @ManuChaudhary: What do you mean by *to draw the circuit*? Do you look for an algorithm which implements preparation of the state? If so, please have a look at the paper I refered to in my linked answer.

Comment: Hi @MartinVesely, I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @ManuChaudhary: Yes, I undestand what you mean. If you look at the paper a told you about, you find here and algorithm how to desing a circuit preparing the desired state. Hence, you will be able to draw the circuit.

Comment: Thank you @MartinVesely for providing me the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
I have added an image for your reference. If you have to create any state but don't know the circuit then you can always initialize the state then using qiskit transpile, you can decompose the circuit in terms of basis gates

Comment: Thank you @prathameshbhole for providing me with such a great code.