# How can I produce the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^N} (|1,0^{N-1}\rangle + |01,0^{N-2}\rangle + ...+|0^{N-1},1\rangle)$

Tags: quantum-gate, superposition

Let's say my algorithm starts with the qubit state $|0^N\rangle$. Is there a possibility to end up in a superposition where every component is made of a bitstring containing exactly an $1$ at on position and only $0$'s on every other position, i.e.
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^N} (|1,0^{N-1}\rangle + |01,0^{N-2}\rangle + ...+|0^{N-1},1\rangle)$

I would like to only use the standard gates/unitary transformations: $X,Y,Z,H, \text{CNOT}$

Comment: This is known as w-state, and you can find good answers for your question here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4350/9474. Note that the normalization factor should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$

Comment: Thanks, the question is answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to construct the above state using the specified gates. States that can be prepared using these gates are called stabilizer states. To quote [this stack exchange post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422718/does-the-w-rangle-state-have-a-stabilizer), "for a stabilizer state, the 1-site reduced density matrices must be maximally mixed or pure, which [W states, like the one on your question] aren't."